# Reading backslash characters literally in c++

Tags: c++, backslash

In my c++ code, I am trying to read \ and / characters literally, but \ is read as being same as /.

My code is this:

```
int x, y;
char orient;
cin >> N >> goalA >> goalB;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    cin >> x >> y >> orient;
    xVal [i] = x;
    yVal [i] = y;
    if (orient = '/')
    {
        orientVal [i] = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        orientVal [i] = 2;
    }
    cout << orientVal[i];
}
```

but even when orient = '\', I get orientVal [i] = 1 instead of 2. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: If using gcc, you could benefit from -Wall or at least -Wparentheses

Answer (score 4):

An assignment is done with `=` and an equality with `==`

So the statement

```
if (orient = '/')
```

should be

```
if (orient == '/')
```

The first statement always evaluates to true irrespective of what `orient` contains. Because in C/C++ a non zero value is True. Your assignment makes the statement to simply as

```
if ('/')
```

which is nothing but

```
if (true)
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `if (orient = '/')` is an assignment that always evaluates to true as a boolean (non-zero).

You want `if (orient == '/')`.

Answer (score 0):

Line

```
if(orient = '/'
```

Should be

```
if ('/' == orient) ...
```